# Trying to understand read write lock and the need for two mutex instead of one

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, mutex, read-write

I have been reading [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock#Using_two_mutexes) about read/write lock and it says to implement it we need two mutexes but why can't we do it with one mutex? I am wondering if my understanding is correct.

- we need to make sure one write is happening at any moment
- we need to make sure no one is reading while it's being written to
- many reads can happen concurrently and its completely fine

Write:

```
// wait until no one is reading concurrently
if (wait(write_lock))
{
  acquire(write_lock)

  // Do the write operation

  release(write_lock)
}
```

Read:

```
// wait until no one is currently writing
if (wait(write_lock))
{
  // Do the read operation atomically
}
```

Comment: The article that you cited shows two different ways to implement a readers/writer lock. The second way uses only one mutex.

Comment: You say "wait until no one is reading concurrently", but your code doesn't do that.    Since the readers don't acquire the write lock, the `wait(write_lock)` and `acquire(write_lock)` will succeed even if some reader is still working.  And there wouldn't normally be any other way for the writer to know whether any reader is reading, except by successfully acquiring a lock that the readers would hold while working.

Comment: You say "do the read operation atomically", but that only helps if the write operation is *also* done atomically.  If you can do that, you don't need mutexes at all.  Locking is needed for larger data structures that can't be fully read or written in a single atomic operation, or for when the platform doesn't provide atomic operations at all.